# Using typeof for my generic type parameter

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection, lambda

I have this code snippet:

```
foreach (var item in allClassesINeedList)
{
   var genericMethod = temp.GetType().GetMethod("GenerateDocument").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(item));
   genericMethod.Invoke(temp, new object[] { item });
}
```

This throws an error:

> "The type or namespace name 'item' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

My aim is to execute for every object in `allClassesINeedList`(its a `List<object>`) my generic method `GenerateSingleDocument` with every object in that list.

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Replace `typeof(item)` with `item.GetType()`

Comment: To expand - `typeof` only works on a type known the compiler at compile-time, e.g. `typeof(IDisposable)`. To find the type of an object, use `GetType()`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use reflection? If you have control of the classes that you are iterating over, it would be better to create an interface. Reflection is slow and should be avoided where possible.

```
public interface IDocumentCreator
{
    void GenerateDocument();
}
```

Add this interface to your classes:

```
public class YourClass : IDocumentCreator
{
    // ...

    public void GenerateDocument()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And then make a `List<IDocumentCreator>` instead of `List<object>`. You can then call the method in the normal way:

```
List<IDocumentCreator> allClassesINeedList = ...
foreach(IDocumentCreator item in allClassesINeedList)
{
    item.GenerateDocument();
}
```

Comment: I like your approach, but in my case I have to use relfection, but thxs :)